# Use external .exe in my C# app

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, shell

I'm actually working on an application which converts files from unix to dos then csv to sql . Actually i got a lot of files so i did a good enumerate function , but i don't have a single idea about launching those 2 .exe in my code and make the files pass through both to fill my SQL tables .

Thanks for listening ! `

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace IMR
{
    class ProgramCSV  
    {     
          //unix2dos et csv2sql_new 
           [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
            public static int Shell(

                string 
                bool Wait = false,
                int Timeout = -1

               )


          // Fonction Main 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("U:/Données FTP INPI/IMR_Donnees_Saisies/tc/flux/2017/06/01/0101/17");

            Console.WriteLine("Recherche de fichier .csv :"); //Fonction de recherche de tout les fichiers .csv
            foreach (var fi in dir.EnumerateFiles("*.csv",SearchOption.AllDirectories)) //On précise qu'on veut tout les répértoires
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            }


            Console.ReadKey(); 
        }

    } 

}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Check [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class and it's Start methods. With this you can start external exe with some parameters, you can pause your app until exe finishes or even run exe without showing window.